# State value is not updating after passing a new value from children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having hard times with this one.

I created a modal (SetLevel) so the user can select a level and after that what I want is to just update my initial state which goes by the name of level . So I pass my prop in handleChange in the SetLevel component like this:

```
const Game = () => {
  
  const [levelOpen,setlevelOpen]=useState(false);
  const [level,setlevel]=useState(1);

  const changedLevel = (newLevel)=>{
    console.log('newLevel',newLevel);
      setlevel(newLevel);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='title'>Find the icons </h1>
      <div className='container'>
       

        <button className='btn' onClick={() => setlevelOpen(true)}>
          Select level
        </button>

        <SetLevel isOpen={levelOpen} handleChange={()=>changedLevel(level)}
        onClose={()=>setlevelOpen(false)}/>

      </div>
      <ItemDrag  newLevel={level}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

SetLevel child component looks like this:

```
const SetLevel = ({isOpen,onClose,handleChange}) => {
    if (isOpen === false) return null;
  const close = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (onClose) {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  const handleClick =(num,e)=>{
    console.log(num);
    handleChange(num)
    close(e)
  }
  
  return (
    
    <div className='modal-window'>
      <div>
        <div onClick={(e) => close(e)} className='modal-close'>
          CLOSE
        </div>
        <h1>Select level!</h1>
       <button className="btn" onClick={(e)=>handleClick(3,e)} >LEVEL3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So here is how I do it if a user selects level 3 I pass that number to my handleClick function and this function should take care of that handleChange prop as you can see.

But whenever I do this my level is not updating how come??  The value i am getting back is always 1 , why is that? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't take the return value of the `handleChange` in the `Game` component.
Try it like this:

```
const Game = () => {
  
  const [levelOpen,setlevelOpen]=useState(false);
  const [level,setlevel]=useState(1);

  const changedLevel = (newLevel)=>{
    console.log('newLevel',newLevel);
      setlevel(newLevel);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='title'>Find the icons </h1>
      <div className='container'>
       

        <button className='btn' onClick={() => setlevelOpen(true)}>
          Select level
        </button>

        <SetLevel isOpen={levelOpen} handleChange={(newLevel)=>changedLevel(newLevel)}
        onClose={()=>setlevelOpen(false)}/>

      </div>
      <ItemDrag  newLevel={level}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Oh... , I should have made this post earlier so it would save me some nerves, thank you!